# Please help identify the species of a possible butterfly

Tags: species-identification, entomology, lepidoptera

I took picture of this weird butterfly. It landed when I was drying my clothes. But it didn't even move when I try to shake it off. After I took a lot of pictures, I tried to shake it outside.
It might not be clear in the picture, but there is a bit of pink on its 2 wings near the body in the next to last picture.

Location: Asia (Southern part, Vietnam), and this butterfly is in the countryside.
Climate: hot, humid, it is currently Raining season, night is cool, day time is not too hot.

This might even be a type of moth?

[image]

Comment: Definitely a moth, probably hawkmoth. Very beautiful

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include an estimate of the size of this insect — that information can be very helpful for identifications. Also, are mango's grown nearby — adding that information is now very relevant given bob1's answer.

Comment: I googled the name, and yes it match up perfectly. I released the moth already, so can't put it with a ruler, but it is around the palm of your hand. Yes, there are plenty of mango trees around my place, sorry I didn't think about adding the surrounding tree type for better reference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm no expert - just like browsing pictures, so totally open to other suggestions.

I think this is the [Mango Hawkmoth/Sphinx moth](https://www.projectnoah.org/spottings/44796012) (*Amplypterus panopus*), which is a fairly widespread moth of SE Asia, including Vietnam and Thailand.

You can see the pink of the underwings (terminology?) [here](http://lepidoptera.butterflyhouse.com.au/sphi/panopus.html) and you can see the big lines across the wings. If you imagine the wings folded so that they lie across the body, you can see the nice horizontal stripes and dark head seen in your photos.